# I found this easter egg, any ideas what kind of encryption it is?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, decryption

I am looking to have the cryptography identified of this encrypted message

```
aHR0cHM6Ly9nb28uZ2wvZXY5SDN1
```

Any ideas what crypto was used here?

Thank you

Comment: It's just base64, nothing to do with cryptography, I'm sure there are plenty of decoders online if you google it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking us to do the 'homework' (solving the ctf challenge) for him, without showing that he has done any minimal work on his own before asking about this obvious base64 text.

Comment: Thank you, hashid identified it as bigcrypt, but it is infact base64